# React.js, Auth Component does not redirect properly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I have created this `Auth` Component and it works fine. Except that, It does not redirect if the unauthenticated user tries to visit `/dashboard`.

The backend, upon receiving `/api/me` request, knows the user by having the cookie. So I have (Cookie-Session) Authentication technique.

```
export const UserContext = createContext();

const Auth = ({ children }) => {
  const [user, setUser] = useState(null);
  const [gotUser, setGotUser] = useState(false);

  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const getUser = async () => {
    const res = await fetch('/api/me');
    const data = await res.json();
    setUser(data);
    if (user) {
      setGotUser(true);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!gotUser) {
      getUser();
    }
  }, [user, gotUser, navigate]);

  if (!user) {
    navigate('/login');
  }
  console.log(user);

  return <UserContext.Provider value={user}>{children}</UserContext.Provider>;
};
```

So the main issue is that no redirection is done. Also, The `user` passed to the context is not updated properly. Maybe because I am confused about what to use in `useEffect`.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The state change in React does not take effect immediately, but on the next render, so right after `setUser(data)`, the `user` state might still be `null`. I don't think you even need the `gotUser` state, the same `user` state should do.

Comment: @tromgy thanks for your clarification, still hope for complete answer

Comment: Hi, sorry I should have noticed that you have used navigate in your JSX while pasting my answer, hence the downvote I think. Glad @DrewReese came to rescue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Issues

There are a couple issues:

1. The "unauthenticated" state matches the "I don't know yet" state (*i.e. the initial state value*) and the component is redirecting too early. It should wait until the `user` state is confirmed.
2. The `navigate` function is called as an unintentional side-effect directly in the body of the component. Either move the `navigate` call into a `useEffect` hook or render the `Navigate` component to issue the imperative navigation action.

## Solution

Use an `undefined` initial `user` state and explicitly check that prior to issuing navigation action ***or*** rendering the `UserContext.Provider` component.

```
const Auth = ({ children }) => {
  const [user, setUser] = useState(); // <-- initially undefined

  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const getUser = async () => {
    try {
      const res = await fetch('/api/me');
      const data = await res.json();
      setUser(data); // <-- ensure defined, i.e. user object or null value
    } catch (error) {
      // handler error, set error state, etc...
      setUser(null); // <-- set to null for no user
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (user === undefined) {
      getUser();
    }
  }, [user]);

  if (user === undefined) {
    return null; // <-- or loading indicator, spinner, etc
  }

  // No either redirect to log user in or render context provider and app
  return user
    ? <Navigate to="/login" replace />
    : <UserContext.Provider value={user}>{children}</UserContext.Provider>;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

`useEffect` runs after your JSX is rendered, so as your code is made, on a page refresh, this `if (!user)` that calls `navigate('/login')` will always pass, as before the `useEffect` does its work, `user` is `null`, that initial value you gave to `useState`. Yet it's not redirecting because `navigate` does not work inside JSX, it should be replaced with `Navigate` the component.

Also, in `getUser`, you have this `if (user)` just after `setUser(data)`, that wouldn't work well as `user` won't get updated immediately, as updating a `state` is an asynchronous task which takes effect after a re-render.

To fix your problems you can add a `checking` state, and return some loader while the user is being verified. Also, you can optimize a little bit your code overall, like getting rid of that `gotUser` state:

```
export const UserContext = createContext();

const Auth = ({ children }) => {
  const [user, setUser] = useState(null);
  const [checking, setChecking] = useState(true);

  const getUser = async () => {
    try {
      const res = await fetch("/api/me");
      const data = await res.json();
      setUser(data);
    } catch (error) {
      setUser(null);
    } finally {
      setChecking(false);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!user) {
      getUser();
    }
  }, [user]);

  if (checking) {
    return <p>Checking...</p>;
  }

  if (!user) {
    return <Navigate to="/login" replace />
  }

  return <UserContext.Provider value={user}>{children}</UserContext.Provider>;
};

export default Auth;
```